# Self referencing in global, static object in CoffeeScript

Tags: object, coffeescript, global, self-reference

Is there any way to accomplish self referencing as below within a global, static object in CS?

```
@Obj
  x: ['string']
  y: [@x]
```

From what I've read, this doesn't seem possible.  Mainly due to the object having not been created yet at time of assignment of `y`.  Some form of getter and setter (e.g.  `__definedSetter__`, `__defineGetter__`, etc.) seem like the most likely options but I would have to turn this object into a class and there are a whole slew of issues with that in CS and I have little reason to do this aside from this self referencing issue.  Is there any workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, this would be possible with a class (you can reference and assign Obj.x to Obj.y in the constructor). If it's a static object, I'd just assign it in a separate line with @Obj.y = [@Obj.x].